# Android Studio Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have some problem with Android Studio
The app has a problem with the Gradle and gives me the following.

```
"Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found."
```

everything is up to date. I saw many things about updating the Gradle, and I update gradle to Gradle 3.4.1,

This is my Gradle Code :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
z
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: You'll need to upgrade `buildToolsVersion` if you are upgrading Gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "z" after the android{} bracket. If this was just a typo and doesn't solve the problem, please post your **project-level** build.gradle file, too.